# Using block statement to detect failed file modification

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a view controller with a `tableview` and each tableview cell has an editable `UILabel` in it.  Each cell is also associated with an audio file.  Whenever the label is edited, I call an `NSObject` subclass that handles my files to rename the audio file to whatever the label was changed to.  I then return the `NSURL` absolute string to store in core data.  My question is, if this process throws an error - such as "file path already exists", how can I get it to show a `UIAlertView` in my view controller and not my `NSObject` subclass.  I'm guessing I need some type of block that returns either a `NSString` or an `NSError`.  I don't have much experience with blocks and any help would be appreciated.

Method in my view controller that calls the NSObject subclass to rename the file

```
recording.audioURL = [self.managedDocument changeFileName:previousPath withNewComponent:textField.text];
```

This is the method in my NSObject subclass that renames the audio file

```
-(NSString*) changeFileName:(NSString*) previousPath withNewComponent:(NSString*)newComponenet
{  
    NSURL * oldURL = [self.url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFiles"];
    oldURL = [oldURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[previousPath lastPathComponent]];

     NSString * trimmedString = [newComponenet stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSURL * newURL = [self.url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFiles"];
    newURL = [newURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:trimmedString];
    newURL = [newURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"];

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError * err;

    BOOL result = [fileManager moveItemAtURL:oldURL toURL:newURL error:&err];

    if(!result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
    }

    return newURL.absoluteString;
}
```

Comment: nsfilenamager is not thread safe, can you check whether all this is happening on main thread ? http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/06/12/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-is-not-thread-safe.html

Comment: @thndrkiss It's perfectly fine to use `NSFileManager` on threads other than the main thread.

Comment: FYI - You must not store an absolute path to the audio file if the file is in your app's sandbox. The sandbox can change. Always use a relative path from your app's sandbox.

Comment: @rmaddy I've never heard of sandbox.  Where can i read more about this?

Comment: Each app is in its own sandbox. Search the iOS docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to follow the example of the `NSFileManager` method you're using. Output an `NSError*` pointer indirectly through a by-reference parameter and make the method's direct return value indicate success or failure:

```
-(NSString*) changeFileName:(NSString*) previousPath withNewComponent:(NSString*)newComponenet error:(NSError**)error
{  
    NSURL * oldURL = [self.url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFiles"];
    oldURL = [oldURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[previousPath lastPathComponent]];

     NSString * trimmedString = [newComponenet stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSURL * newURL = [self.url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFiles"];
    newURL = [newURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:trimmedString];
    newURL = [newURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"];

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL result = [fileManager moveItemAtURL:oldURL toURL:newURL error:error];

    if(!result)
        return nil;

    return newURL.absoluteString;
}
```

In the caller, check the return value to determine if it failed and, if so, present the error.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen this approach.  I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but I'm unable to print the error message in my `UIAlertView`.  Is this wrong `UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:error delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];`

Comment: @thndrkiss I'm getting a warning because of `error` in the alertView saying "incompatible pointer types sending NSError to parameter of type NSString"

Comment: try error.localizedDescription https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/localizedDescription or you can also try NSLog(@"error %@",error);